# Call a function after a specific time

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and I have a question. I have two clauses:

```
perform([X,Y], move(west),  [NX,Y]) :- NX is X - 1, !.
perform([X,Y], move(south), [X,NY]) :- NY is Y - 1, !.
```

X and Y are my coordinates. All I want is something like this:

```
perform([X,Y], move(west), [NX,Y]):- NX is X - 1, !.
if NX == abs(Y)
perform([X,Y], move(west), [NX,Y]):- NX is X - 1, !.
else
perform([X,Y], move(south), [NX,NY]):- NY is Y - 1, !.
```

Basically move(west) and if my X coordinate is someValue move(south).

Comment: Title of this question is somehow misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
perform([X,Y], move(west),  [NX,Y]) :- NX is X - 1, !.
perform([X,Y], move(south), [X,NY]) :- NY is Y - 1, !.

NX == abs(Y) -> perform([X,Y], move(west), [NX,Y]);
                perform([X,Y], move(south), [NX,NY]).
```

or

```
NX == abs(Y) -> NX is X - 1;
                NY is Y - 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to achieve the conditional action you need.

Example 1 - condition made with math expression (not the most readable one):

```
perform2([X,Y], move(west),  [NX,NY]) :-
    NX is X - 1,
    NY is Y - 1*0^(NX-abs(Y)),
    !.
```

Example 2 - condition made with operators `->/2` and `;/2`:

```
perform3([X,Y], move(west),  [NX,NY]) :-
    NX is X - 1,
    (    NX =:= abs(Y) -> NY is Y - 1; NY = Y ),
    !.
```

Example 3 - condition made with separate clauses:

```
perform4([X,Y], move(west),  [NX,NY]) :-
    NX is X - 1,
    NX =:= abs(Y),
    NY is Y - 1,
    !.

perform4([X,Y], move(west),  [NX,Y]) :-
    NX is X - 1,
    NX =\= abs(Y),
    !.
```

For all above predicates input and output looks like this:

```
?- perform4([1,0], move(west), X).
X = [0, -1].

?- perform4([2,0], move(west), X).
X = [1, 0].
```

Comment: When I try perform4([0,1], move(west), X). it returns false. Why? Why is not X = [-1, 0]?

Comment: @user3662959, for me `perform4([0,1], move(west), X)` returns `X = [-1, 1].`. Other versions of `performX/3` do the same.

Comment: @user3662959, which Prolog interpreter do you use? I use SWI-Prolog.

Comment: Can you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812532/guiding-a-robot-in-an-infinit-space